# __attribute__((NSObject)) auto-synthesized property doesn't get released in dealloc

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, properties, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I want a property backed by a strong reference but which has a Core Foundation object type (not Objective-C object type) in ARC. I believe the proper way to do this was to mark it with `__attribute__((NSObject))` and ARC will manage it just like an Objective-C object type property (i.e. release and retain on assign, and release when the containing object is `dealloc`ed):

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) CFArrayRef bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
// property bar is auto-synthesized
@end
```

(I know `CFArray` is toll-free bridged to `NSArray`. This is just for the sake of an example. The real use case is for a Core Foundation type that does not have toll-free bridging.)

But when I put an object into the `bar` property of a `Foo` object and let the `Foo` object go out of scope and get `dealloc`ed, the object in `bar` is leaked because it is not released when the `Foo` object is deallocated, as it would with a regular Objective-C object type property:

```
void someFunc(void) {
  Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
  CFArrayRef arr = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 42, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
  foo.bar = arr;
  CFRelease(arr);
}
```

The code compiles without any warnings or errors, and passes Analyze with no issues. The Leaks instrument detects that the mutable array was leaked.

Is this a compiler bug? I am using the latest Xcode (8.3.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is curious wording in the [ARC specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), when defining *retainable object pointer* the last kind is defined as:

> typedefs marked with `__attribute__((NSObject))`

Note that this uses *typdefs* and not *declarations*. The phrasing is used again a little further in the spec. This *almost* seems to suggest you need to use a `typedef` for the attribute to be recognised, which would be a curious design.

Unfortunately when it comes to property declarations the spec says (emphasis added):

> Applying `__attribute__((NSObject))` to a property not of retainable object pointer type has the same behavior it does outside of ARC: it requires the property type to be some sort of pointer and permits the use of modifiers other than `assign`. These modifiers only affect the synthesized getter and setter; direct accesses to the ivar (even if synthesized) still have primitive semantics, and *the value in the ivar will not be automatically released during deallocation*.

This does appear to explain the behaviour you are seeing - the design is half-baked, the getter/setter adopt the semantics but deallocation doesn't.

Given the spec wording your one hope for automatic support seems to be to first create an attributed typedef for CF type and then use that in the property declaration... Weird if true, but it fits the curious wording... Sorry can't check this at the moment, but I'm guessing disappointment will be the outcome. Try assigning `nil` to the property in the `dealloc` as that uses the setter which (according to the spec) has the correct semantics.

HTH

Comment: It does seem to work with a typedef `typedef __attribute__((NSObject)) CFArrayRef MyArrayRef;` and defining `bar` as a `MyArrayRef`

Comment: Good news for you, but what were Apple thinking? Let's be polite and call it an "interesting" language design. (This sort of thing can happen when you write the compiler first, and then the spec - immortalising any implementation quirks. But maybe Apple have a justification of the curious semantics.)